# Visual Basic load a lot of controls smoothly

Tags: vb.net

When i start up my form it has to load a lot of usercontrols and binding data to each one. This causes the form to take a few seconds to delay before it shows. What would be the best way to have the controls load one by one in a flow layout panel and show them as they are added?

Comment: Which version of Visual Basic are you using?

Comment: Visual Basic 2013 express. What i did now was have the form load first and then call a public subroutine to load the controls using panel.refresh after each control is added. This seems to work now. Is this a good way to do it, or is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The time it takes to 'paint' controls on a form is the main cause of this problem. Calling `Refresh()` is probably only making the problem worse.

The solution is to suspend all of the framework's layout logic until you've initialized all of your controls.

```
Private Sub InitializeControls()
   Me.SuspendLayout()
   ' ...
   ' ...
   ' ...
   Me.ResumeLayout()
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

My answer assumes that whatever datasource you are binding to isn't the bottleneck.
If it is, you'll gain much more by making your code asynchronous.

Comment: no the binding happens pretty quick, I'll try this method. Thanks